# Map BasicNameValuePair from JSON with Jackson

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, jackson

I'm currently trying to deserialize an API result, which looks like the following

```
[{"name":"MyName","value":"MyValue"},{"name":"MyName2","value":"MyValue2"}]
```

```
ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> entities = JsonUtils.getObjectMapper()
    .readValue(receivedData.toString(),
    new TypeReference<ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>>() {});
```

Then the following exceptions occurs

```
Exception mapping result.
No suitable constructor found for type...
```

Since this is an internal class from `org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair`, I can not annotate or edit it in any way. But I see (from other android projects) a lot of people using this class. Is there some way to get this working? Serializing to `String` from `BasicNameValuePair` works.

Comment: that's an array of maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jackson uses reflection to create an instance of your class. By default, it expects a no-arg constructor. The `BasicNameValuePair` class does not have such a constructor. It has a constructor with two parameters, one for `name` and one for `value`.

Typically, if you had control of the class, you could annotate the constructor parameters with `@JsonProperty` so that Jackson used that constructor instead of the no-arg constructor. Since you don't have control of the code, use Mixins.

Declare a class like so

```
public static abstract class BasicNameValuePairMixIn {
     private BasicNameValuePairMixIn(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("value") String value) { }
}
```

And configure your `ObjectMapper` like so

```
// configuration for Jackson/fasterxml 
objectMapper.addMixInAnnotations(BasicNameValuePair.class, BasicNameValuePairMixIn.class);
```

Jackson will now use the mixin as a template for your class.

If you are using the older version of Jackson, use the configuration as described [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations).

Comment: You are a god and I praise you!

Answer (score -2):

Try not to use reserve keywords in your parameter names and then try again. "name","value"

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Can you clarify?

Comment: I don't understand it either.